# Передача переменной в Django из SQL в определённое время

Tags: python-3.x, django

Может кто подскажет с решением вопроса.

В views.py есть переменная которая отвечает за дату последней записи в SQL. Которая в дальнейшем уже передается в шаблон. значение последней записи в SQL получаю из функции в settings.py.

views.py:

```
from apps.home.settings import ED

@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def index(request):
    ed = request.GET.get('ed', ED)
    context = {'segment': 'index', 'ED': ed}

    html_template = loader.get_template('home/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(html_template.render(context, request))
```

settings.py:

```
sql_last_day = SQL_Requeste("SELECT SD FROM 'dayli' ORDER BY SD DESC LIMIT 1", 'one')
ED = sql_last_day[0]
```

БД обновляется раз в сутки и если Django не перезапустить, то переменная висит со значение полученным при запуске. Можно как-то реализовать чтобы ed обновлялось например с загрузкой страницы? Как вариант рассматривал через цикл while сделать, чтобы переменная в определённое время обновлялась, но может есть более простой вариант?